# Building a Search Engine Based on Lexical Frequency Tables/Distributions?

Tags: web-applications, search-engine, keyword, frequency, lexical-analysis

I am admittedly a "n00b" when it comes to a lot of web development know-how, so please bear with me.

I have an idea for a website, and part of that idea involves scanning particular webpages, and then building ranked tables of "keywords" by frequency (with context considered) in order to build "profiles" for said pages.

My question is two-fold:

A) What programming language would be best suited for this purpose (fast, and specifically good for working with large volumes of data).

B) What sort of data-structure should I be using to create these frequency tables in order for fast and efficient analysis/comparison with other pages/tables? Also, how should I store the tables themselves so that I can quickly skim through them and determine relevance? I essentially want to create a search engine based on certain heuristics and for certain content.

This idea as of now is bigger then me, but I want to tackle it.

Answer (score 1):

First reasonable answers, then some explanation.

a). Any language. Almost any programming language will work.
b). All types of structures. This depends on the specific task.

There is an area of the computer science called "data mining". Try to search on these keywords. There are tons of systems and libraries, like SOLR, Mallet, Serene, RapidMiner, R. Different libraries use different languages. I would recommend to start with the one that you are most familiar with.

Maybe read this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Comment: I've been reading a lot about data mining... for this task I want to basically build a frequency distribution of popular words for each item in the database (each has a profile page online somewhere). Then, the user enters keywords, hits search, and I need an algorithm which can compare the given keys against my gigantic list of frequency distributions to find the best match. Going to use MySQL for the db, but I am still wondering what the quickest way to find the match would be... because I see this taking an obscenely long time. Would hash tables make sense in a situation like this?